# How load gets divide/handled in distributed jmeter testing?

Tags: jmeter

I have 7 requests and 100 thread users in 1 Master and 3 Slave systems.

I want to know how load gets handled in slave systems?

What is  response timeout in JMeter?

Comment: How can we use Master as well to simulate more load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per what I'm understanding is that you have set up below mentioned architecture for JMeter distributed testing,

1 Master: Controlling 3 Slaves.

You have set up number of threads to 100 in the Thread Group.

In your Thread Group you have 7 HTTP Requests.

So now if you run your test with Remote Start All option, the Master system will tell all the 3 Salve system to execute the srcipt that will make 7 HTTP Requests each for 100 users. The Mster system in return will collect the results of all the three slaves.

So now in this scenario you are generating a load of 300 users simultaneously for each of your 7 HTTP Requests.

**Now for the response timeout in Jmeter:** Default timeout is 30 seconds I guess. Although you have configure your own timeout limit. There are 2 ways to configure custom response timeouts,

You can configure it in the Timeouts section in HTTP Request Sampler.

[image]

You can also configure it in the Timeouts section in HTTP Request Defaults config element.

[image]

Comment: thank you for answer, virtually it creates 300 users for 3 slaves? what is standard response timeout?

Comment: Yes it creates 300 virtual users for 3 slaves. I've mentioned about the default timeout in the answer. For browsers I guess the default timeout is 30 or 60 seconds.

Comment: ramup time is also added?

Answer (score 2):

1. All JMeter slaves are basically executing the script from master machine. So if you have 100 threads in Thread Group each slave will kick off 100 threads hence total load will be 300 threads. Master machine does not generate any load (unless you launch a slave at the same host)
2. By default all JMeter timeouts to wit:

   - Connect Timeout (until connection is established
   - Socket Timeout (waiting for data or between 2 data packets)

   are set to zero. It means that JMeter will try to establish connection or wait for response forever.

You can use `Connect` and `Response` timeouts setting of the [HTTP Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) in order to control the timeout values. You can also apply the desired timeout values to all HTTP Request samplers in one shot using [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/http-request-defaults)

[image: HTTP Request Defaults - Timeouts]

Response threshold can be set via [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion)